# How do I dynamically render the maximum amount of table rows that will fit within an unknown screen size? Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svelte

I'm very new to front end development. I have a table with rows that are each of 52px height. I want to fill the screen with as many rows as possible (and paginate the remainder that don't fit on an arbitrary screen size).

I know I have to divide some element size by 52 to figure out what the amount is. What I don't know is which element size, or difference of elements, do I use in the numerator to reliably do this.

I have the window size, the nav bar size, then the main container where I will have the changing content of the website.

My hunch is I can just use the main container size, subtract the size of the header and the page select bar on the bottom, and then I have my number which I can use for my condition.

Again, I'm not sure if this is a reliable method. If it is, is there someway to determine these numbers with svelte itself? Like how `<svelte:window />` works? Or do I have to rely on the DOM directly?

Here's a screenshot of the problem so far:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsFgS.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "hunch" is correct. To fill the screen with as many rows as possible, you could just do something like this:

```
  $: availableRows = Math.floor((windowHeight - headerHeight - pageSelectBarHeight) / rowHeight);
```